# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to access Selenium JAR files on build path. Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jar, buildpath

I'm new to Selenium. The class file is saying that "The JAR file [my path] has no source attachment."

I recently downloaded Selenium and I'm trying to run with Java. I extracted the files to a folder. I added the all JAR files including the ones inside the lib folder to my Modulepath by right clicking on the project -> Properties and clicking "Add External JARs" on the Build Path. Then I ran the following program . I've watched about every youtube video I can on the topic and am about to try on a different IDE. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question will soon be closed as there is no enough detail `code` provided. I would suggest you to use use `WebDriver Manager` Instead of manually managing JAR files,

Comment: It is more common to use Maven to manage required dependencies rather than add them manually via _Add External JARs_.

Comment: When adding these jars manually you want to make sure to leave out the ones marked "-sources".  Those will be the same as the non-"-sources" versions and will cause namespace issues/conflicts.  You shouldn't need the sources here, but if you like I think you can right-click on each and set them as the javadoc.